# Interpreting the effect size for a categorical response variable, when the exploratory variable is also categorical

Tags: categorical-data, modeling, effect-size

Please find the following reproducible code in R.

```r
if (!require(NHANES)) install.packages('NHANES')
if (!require(rpart)) install.packages('rpart')
if (!require(devtools)) install.packages('devtools')
if (!require(statisticalModeling)) devtools::install_github("dtkaplan/statisticalModeling")

# Loading libraries
library(NHANES)
library(rpart)
library(statisticalModeling)

# Building the recursive partitioning model
model_rpart <- rpart(Depressed ~ LittleInterest, data = NHANES)

# Calculating the effect size
effect_size_rpart <- effect_size(model_rpart, ~ LittleInterest)

# Printing the effect size
effect_size_rpart
```

The result

[image]

Some background info about the data and model I made;

Here the model has `Depressed` as the response variable and `LittleInterest` as the explanatory variable. Please note that here both the variables are categorical. Here little interest denotes interest in doing something on a given day.

The levels for `Depressed` are; “None” = No sign of depression, “Several” = Individual was depressed for less than half of the survey period days, “Most” = Individual was depressed more than half of the days.

The levels for `LittleInterest` are also similar to that of `Depressed`; "None", "Several" and "Most", and are analogous to levels of `Depressed`.

**Following paragraphs describe how I interpreted the results and I would like to know if my interpretation is right**

We got the effect size values and they are given in two columns; 'change.None' and 'change.Several'. Since our explanatory variable is categorical, effect size values with a categorical response variable give the change in probability values. Here, notice that the effect size is calculated as the difference when the response variable is changing its category from 'None' to 'Several'. That difference is the probability difference from the base value, which is zero.

To make more sense, imagine we get an effect size value of zero, in both the columns, in the above case. This means that when the level of little interest changes from 'None' to 'Several', there is no increase or decrease in the probability of depression is 'None' or 'Several'. This means if a person is having a depressed state of 'None', changing little interest from 'None' to 'Several' will not evoke a change in that person's depressed state. Thus zero is taken as the base value.

Now let us look at the actual effect size values we got. As the level of little interest is changing from 'None' to 'Several', we get a probability difference of -0.4466272 = ~ 0.45 for depression is 'None'. This means that there is a reduction of 45% in the base value of probability. In other words, the person is 45% less likely to have depression set to 'None'. Likewise, in the same notion, the person is 36% more likely to have a depressed state of 'Several', when little interest changes from 'None' to 'Several'.

I am making a tutorial so I want to make sure I am correct. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using ordinal variables, not variables that are strictly categorical. Consequently, you might want to use a different example for your tutorial.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why ordinal category variables are not a good option here?

Comment: There is structure in an ordered variable that is not present in an unordered variable. They are different problems. // If you have further questions about ordinal vs categorical variables (in regression models or otherwise), please post as a separate question so others can benefit from formal answers.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Should I also delete this question then?

Comment: This seems like a legitimate inquiry. Unless you start getting downvotes, I see no need to delete the question.